# Gedmo multiple database connections not listening correctly

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

When trying to create an entity with the @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create") annotation, I am getting "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'created' cannot be null"

It also doesn't work for Gedmo\Slug.

It works when using the default entity manager, but not when using master or creation.

In my config.yml I have the following configuration:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en
    translation_fallback: true
    orm:
        default:
            timestampable: true
            sluggable: true
        master:
            timestampable: true
            sluggable: true
        creation:
            timestampable: true
            sluggable: true
```

In my services.yml I have the following:

```
gedmo.listener.timestampable:
    class: Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: creation }
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: master }
    calls:
         - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]
gedmo.listener.sluggable:
    class: Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: master }
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: creation }
    calls:
        - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]
```

It seems like the event_subscriber is not working correctly.

I am running Symfony 2.3.2 with the StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.

The entity for creating a slug has this:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"})
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $slug;
```

The entity for created has this:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
 */
private $created;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post more of your model?

Comment: I've updated with this. It also doesn't work for Slug, so that's making me think it is something a little more deep rooted.

Comment: Thanks - they look fine. Can you get it to work if you disable the other databases and just use default?

Comment: Yep, works with default. But due to the nature of the application I need them to work with the other two. :(

Comment: Sorry to bring it up. Have you found a solution?